# SharePoint Online - Excel Web Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-web-access-webpart

My worksheet contains button (form control/ActiveX) but SharePoint Online/Excel Web Access does not display it.  The button just mainly print another worksheet (printer-friendly version).  Is there another way of accomplishing this without needing to open Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Controls are unsupported in Excel Online. You need to open it in Excel.

> Controls, such as ActiveX controls and form toolbar controls, prevent a workbook from being viewed in a browser window.

More information, you can refer to:
[Differences between using a workbook in the browser and in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-F0DC28ED-B85D-4E1D-BE6D-5878005DB3B6#__functions)